# I have a project idea on Smart Lighting System. How can I do the simulation for this?

Tags: project, computer-science, iot

Currently I am working on this project to provide the layout of a smart street light system with energy saving function based on sensor network for energy management. The proposal is an autonomous-distributed-controlled light system, in which the lights turn on before pedestrians come and turn off or reduce power when there is no one by means of a distributed-installed sensor network.

I will be adding a few things to the project for energy reduction but what I need to know is how do I perform the simulation to show that this approach would reduce energy consumption?

Comment: I think such a system requires real life testing - thats because how is your system sure that a car, humans on bycycles or humans walking are in range instead of cats, dogs or even leafs in the wind are in range? Also you need an energymeter to measure the energy flow with and without your system. Last but not least what is more interesting is the point of material costs + energy costs of your system vs. the already existing systems.

Comment: Doing real life testing would be quite heavy on the cost side right? I plan to implement my idea in a similar way as done  [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323560518_IoT-enabled_Smart_Lighting_Systems_for_Smart_Cities) . Is there any way to perhaps do this?